# Templated Constructor Specialization

Tags: c++, c++17

How can one specialize a templated constructor?

e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
    int x = 0;
    float y = 0;
public:
    template< typename T >
    MyClass( T foo ): y { foo }
    { }

    template< >
    MyClass< int >( int foo ): x { foo }
    { }
};
```

If there isn't a way, what's the alternative? Making a member function that's specialized and calling that?

Comment: Seems one can't do this specialization. Compiler support for specializing c'tor templates is sketchy, even it's perfectly legal standard-wise.

Comment: You code does not compile for different reasons then your question implies. You are trying to instatiate `std::unordered_map` with `MyClass` within the definition of `MyClass`.

Comment: @nowi The definition of `MyClass` is still incomplete when you try to create a `std::unordered_map<..., MyClass>`. You can't instatiate a `std::unordered_map` with an incomplete type. You could swap to storing `MyClass*`, or `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>`. With unique_ptr you can't use list initialization for the map though, you need to add the elements with `emplace`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: @nowi You have the right to delete your account, if you'd like, but not your posts. For deleting your account, I'd suggest you read [How do I delete my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 4):

You can always overload instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    int x = 0;
    float y = 0;
public:
    template <typename T>
    MyClass(T foo): y{foo}
    { }

    MyClass(int foo): x{foo}
    { }
};
```

While we are on this topic you could read this article from Herb Sutter [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: also, try and use a more standard white spacing policy, like in my answer. Your's very strange and confusing.

Comment: @nowi then you have a textbook [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @nowi You should add that information to your question along with the code that reproduces it. It's almost certainly because you are passing something that's not an exact match in type (different cv-qualification or needs an implicit conversion) to the `int` constructor, and then the template is considered a better match.