# Explicitly specialize templated constructor with zero arguments

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization, explicit-specialization

Suppose the following class:

```cpp
class JsonDocument
{
public:
    using RootType = size_t;
    constexpr static RootType ObjectRoot = 1;
    constexpr static RootType ArrayRoot = 2;

    template<
        RootType T = ObjectRoot,
        std::enable_if<T == ObjectRoot || T == ArrayRoot>
    >
    JsonDocument();

    JsonDocument(const std::string &json_str);
};
```

I want to specialize `JsonDocument` constructor for both `ObjectRoot` and `ArrayRoot`. The problem is, as there are no arguments, `T` couldn't be inferred. Explicitly specializing it doesn't work, neither this way:

```cpp
class JsonDocument
{
    // ...

    // Doesn't work
    template<> JsonDocument<ObjectRoot>();
    template<> JsonDocument<ArrayRoot>();
}
```

Nor this:

```cpp
template<> JsonDocument::JsonDocument<ObjectRoot>()
{
}

template<> JsonDocument::JsonDocument<ArrayRoot>()
{
}
```

So is it impossible at all? Is there any way to do it?

**P.S.:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60408253/4215651) is different; as deduction can be made.

Comment: Even if you are able to specialize the constructor, you will not be able to call a specific one. There is simply no syntax for it. See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861839/can-the-template-parameters-of-a-constructor-be-explicitly-specified?rq=2

Comment: It is intentionally impossible, because the constructor doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow this as also explained in [Is it possible to have a constructor template with no parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/is-it-possible-to-have-a-constructor-template-with-no-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Make the whole class a template. I think this makes sense because you are going to select which root to use at compile time anyway. (C++17 example)

```
#include <type_traits>

struct ObjectRoot
{};

struct ArrayRoot
{};

// helper constexpr for readability (in C++20 consider a concept)
template<typename root_t>
constexpr bool is_valid_json_root = std::is_same_v<root_t, ObjectRoot> || std::is_same_v<root_t, ArrayRoot>;

template<typename root_t,typename enable_t = void>
class JsonDocument;

template<typename root_t>
class JsonDocument<root_t,std::enable_if_t<is_valid_json_root<root_t>>>
{
public:
    // no need for compile time constants. 
    // you make the selection for your root_t at compile time anyway
    //using RootType = size_t;
    //constexpr static RootType ObjectRoot = 1;
    //constexpr static RootType ArrayRoot = 2;

    JsonDocument() {}


};

int main()
{
    JsonDocument<ObjectRoot> doc_from_root;
    JsonDocument<ArrayRoot> doc_from_array;
}
```

Comment: From the design perspective for my use case, templatizing the class doesn't make sense. I've edited my question to also include another non-template constructor. If one wants to use that specific constructor, instantiating the class template doesn't make sense. BTW, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I would need to know more about what you would try to do. But you might be able to inject a node handling (root/array) policy as template parameter to the whole class. If this strategy cannot be known at compile time then using templates may not be the best choice anyway.  And you could add a non-template factory method (and let that call either of one specific non-template constructor). E.g. add two static methods : `static JsonDocument JsonDocument::FromRoot()` and `static JsonDocument JsonDocument::FromArray()` or something similar